# How to add rounded corner view inside another layout .xml- Android

Tags: android

I am trying to display a `list` using an own `layout` that's going to be populated with some info fetched from the server. I would like to create my own `layout`(to use it in `ListView`), to have in the right and left top corners some `rounded views`, to display time and date. I have found an exemple online as follows:
[image]

My question it's: How can i achieve this? What must be done in the `root layout` of the `ListView` to create that `round view` in the the corners? I have searched online and nothing popped. The `layout` presented above it's a screenshot from another application, that uses the same logic. (Creating a `ListView` with a `root layout`)

Comment: you have to create a rounded corner template(*style) for text view & apply it to the text view of child view which is gonna populated in the list view, not in the parent list view it self

Comment: I have been thinking about that. But as you can see in the picture added above, the `blue view` it's somehow outside of the parent view, as the top right corner would be out

Comment: I'm a bit confused, does every text view in your list gonna have that blue circle?

Comment: @Blu No, I would like to add a blue circle in the top left corner of the parent view(mirrored version of the photo), and another blue circle in the right top corner(exactly as in the photo above)

Comment: soo, you can try adding a frame & applying that custom design template on both top corners & after that, inflate your list below to it.. inside the frame, is that what you want?

Comment: you've actually lost me. can you show me an exemple? I am pretty sure that with a given example I'll manage to create what i'm looking for.

Comment: okay, let me try

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution, probably not the best way to do it but the outcome is as follows:
[image]

I have used a `RelativeLayout` as parent, with 2 views aligned to left and right, and to make them go out of the parent, used on both `android:marginStart` and `android:marginEnd` plus `android:marginTop` with negative values. The code is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="-8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:text="32''"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buton_rotund_albastru" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="-8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:text="32''"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buton_rotund_albastru"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: that's the same thing I was telling about. make the UI in parent view & add the list view below it

Comment: @Blu the magic comes from the `android:marginTop` with negative value. that was actually what I needed to find